# How to get file metadata from Azure File Share?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-storage, storage-file-share

I'm trying to get File Share Metadata from Azure file share using npm [storage-file-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-file-share).

Code snippet as below, but didn't find anything in documentation where to get metadata.

Is there any way to get metadata from azure library or has to call [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file-metadata)?

```
const serviceClient = new ShareServiceClient(
      `https://${storageAccountName}.file.core.windows.net`,
      credential
    );
    const directoryClient  = serviceClient.getShareClient(shareName).getDirectoryClient(directoryPath);
    const dirIter = directoryClient.listFilesAndDirectories();
    const list = [];
    for await (const item of dirIter) {
        list.push({name: item.name, metadata????}); // Need item metadata 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [getProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-share/sharefileclient?view=azure-node-latest#getproperties-filegetpropertiesoptions-) method for `fetching metadata` for the `file` and `directory`. Here is the definition of this method:

> Returns all **user-defined metadata**, standard HTTP properties, and
> system properties for the file. It does not return the content of the
> file.

So in your code -> inside `for await (const item of dirIter)`, you need to determine if it's a `file` or `directory`, then call the `getProperties()` method. The sample code looks like below:

```
for await (const item of dirIter) {
      if (item.kind === "directory") {
        
        const mydirectory = directoryClient.getDirectoryClient(item.name);
        var diretory_properties = await mydirectory.getProperties();

        //for test, you can print out the metadata
        console.log(diretory_properties.metadata);

        //here, you can write code to add the metadata in your list

      } else {
        
        const myfile=directoryClient.getFileClient(item.name);
        var the_properties = await myfile.getProperties();

        //for test, you can print out the metadata
        console.log(the_properties.metadata)

       //here, you can write code to add the metadata in your list

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`getShareMetadata`](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/FileService.html)

```
fileService.getShareMetadata(shareName, function (error, result, response) {
```